# When placing a new line it doesn't get assigned a net, how to fix it in Altium?

Tags: altium, routing, cad

I had this working well before, but now, every time i'm placing a new line from a component, it never gets assigned the net.

[image]

In the Net field it is always "No Net", which forces me to manually place the name of the net everytime.

[image]

How can it be fixed using Altium 18?

Comment: You should be placing a track or a trace, not a line (even though it ends up as the same thing).

Comment: You're right. I was finding it strange because it seems the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Place -> Line`  (Shortcut `P L`) for routing.

You're looking for `Route -> Interactive Routing` (Shortcut `U T`)